# Twitter error message "There was an error updating the list"

Tags: twitter

What does the error message "There was an error updating the list" mean? I got it while trying to add someone to a new, private, list using twitter's web site with Safari.

Speculation includes:

1. [Too many users in a list](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/blogging/TCH_BLG/747121-18428456)
2. [Too many lists](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/blogging/TCH_BLG/747121-18428456)
3. [Browser issues](https://getsatisfaction.com/twitter/topics/i_cant_delete_a_list_or_remove_anyone_from_a_list#reply_1845255)
4. [A bug in twitter](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110423171023AAmSGta)

Comment: It's probably one of those generic errors to cover all sorts of issues

Comment: @EightDays sounds right. Can you Make that comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those generic error messages that are used to cover all sorts of issues.

It allows the website or web app to provide a level of abstraction so that users only need to know that something is up and to either wait a bit before they retry or follow-up with support or the developers.

It's deliberately vague because the user doesn't need to know the exact details of what's gone wrong which may include:

- timeout issues
- temporary code changes
- permission errors from missed database connections
- etc.

These things are usually temporary and retrying later usually will go through fine.

If not, then the error message will show more details or there will be a related post on the site or its blog to detail what's happening and/or why.